# Changing the name of filedset elements while cloning with javascript

Tags: javascript, fieldset

I have a requirement in which I had to add a duplicate of the existing fieldset in a form. I'm able to achieve the cloning process successfully. But I'm not able to change the name and id of the filedset elements. It is the same as the first fieldset but I want it to be with a different name and id to differentiate it(even adding a number at the end would be fine). Below are my js and fieldset.

```
<div id="placeholder">
<div id="template">
<fieldset id="fieldset">
<legend id="legend">Professional development</legend>
<p>Item                     <input type ="text" size="25"   name="prof_itemDYNID" id ="prof_item_id"/><br /></p>
<p>Duration                 <input type ="text" size="25"   name="prof_durationDYNID"  id="prof_duration_id" /><br /></p>
<p>Enlargement              <label for="enlargement"></label><p></p>
                            <textarea name="textareaDYNID" cols="71" rows="5" id="prof_enlargement">
</textarea></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Add new item" id="add_prof"  onclick="Add();" /></p>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>

function Add() {

    var oClone = document.getElementById("template").cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(oClone);
}
```

Also, this is just a sample fieldset and it will be different as well. I heard that this can be done using regex but not sure how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes the best(as per my assumption) answer to the above problem..

```
function addMe(a){

    var original = a.parentNode;

        while (original.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'fieldset')
    {
        original = original.parentNode;
    }
    var duplicate = original.cloneNode(true);

   var changeID= duplicate.id;

   var counter = parseInt(changeID.charAt(changeID.length-1));
     ++counter;
   var afterchangeID = changeID.substring(0,changeID.length-1);
    var newID=afterchangeID + counter;
    duplicate.id = newID;
    var tagNames = ['label', 'input', 'select', 'textarea'];
        for (var i in tagNames)
        {

    var nameChange = duplicate.getElementsByTagName(tagNames[i]);

        for (var j = 0; j < nameChange.length; j++)
    {if (nameChange[j].type != 'hidden'){
        var elementName = nameChange[j].name;

                var afterSplitName = elementName.substring(0,elementName.length-1);

             nameChange[j].name = afterSplitName + counter;


        var elementId = nameChange[j].id;

                var afterSplitId = elementId.substring(0,elementId.length-1);

                    nameChange[j].id = afterSplitId + counter;


    }
        }
}

    insertAfter(duplicate, original);
}

function insertAfter(newElement, targetElement)
{
    var parent = targetElement.parentNode;
    if (parent.lastChild == targetElement)
    {
        parent.appendChild(newElement);
    }
    else
    {
        parent.insertBefore(newElement, targetElement.nextSibling);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this could be achieve using regex, but somewhat following code should work...

```
var copyNode = original.cloneNode(true);
copyNode.setAttribute("id", modify(original.getAttribute("id")));
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the response. This just changes the id of the DIV element (template) and not the text field or text area inside the fieldset.